# Logo (em svg) aparece no Mozilla e não no Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image: Imagem do problema]

Como podem ver na imagem, o logo está aparecendo no Mozilla e no Chrome não.
Testei ate mesmo no Internet Explorer e também aparece, o que me leva a crer que o problema acontece exclusivamente no Chrome.

Alguem tem ideia do que pode ser?

Um trecho do meu código:

HTML:

```
<header id="main-Header">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-Logo">
        <img src="img/logo.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="main-Title">
        <h1>Lamonier</h1>
        <p>Web Design inteligente e com alta performance,</p>
        <p>utilizando as melhores tecnologias atuais</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-Header{
height: 0px;
background: rgb(89,103,255);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(89,103,255,1) 0%, rgba(144,65,255,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(89,103,255,1) 0%,rgba(144,65,255,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(89,103,255,1) 0%,rgba(144,65,255,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5967ff', endColorstr='#9041ff',GradientType=0 );
display: flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#main-Header .main-Logo{
display: flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: No StackOverflow inglês existem várias soluções para esse tipo de problema, veja se alguma resolve o seu: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/10737166/8133067 , (2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/41195669/8133067 , (3) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5321984/8133067

Comment: Irei varificar e logo comunico o resultado.Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Resolvido,Obrigado!

Comment: Se puder posta uma resposta (para a sua própria pergunta), descrevendo qual método você usou para resolver o problema, assim fica documentado e pode ajudar outras pessoas. De nada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema estava na forma em que eu tratava a imagem,ou seja,com a tag **IMG**

```
<img src="img/logo.svg">
```

Aparentemente o Chrome não lida com formatos svg utilizando a tag **IMG**

A solução foi tratar como objeto da seguinte forma:

```
<object data="img/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<object data="img/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`
Tem algo estranho, utilizo Chrome v104.0.5112.69 e para mim, todas as SVGs carregam, normalmente, utilizando a TAG `<figure>` como container de `<img>`